# Angular 2 translations with Webpack

Tags: angular, internationalization, webpack

I'm trying to follow the Angular cookbook for [internationalization](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html), but we're using Webpack instead of SystemJS.
In the cookbook there's the following snippet:

```
function getTranslationsWithSystemJs(file: string) {
  return System.import(file + '!text'); // relies on text plugin
}
```

It uses SystemJS for loading the translation file. What should we use instead?

Comment: Do you use angular-cli ?

Comment: No, not in this project but I haven't started it. It might have been started with angular-cli because I see it in package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

From webpack 2 you can use `System.import('./relative/path_to/messages.' + locale + '.xlf')` and Webpack will fetch the file and will avoid scanning files that are obvious not a possible match.

**Original**

There are (supposedly) several ways to solve that, but this one worked best for me:

In my i18n-providers.js:

```
function getTranslationFilesWithWebpack(locale: string) {
    const translationFile = `./assets/locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`;
    return require('' + translationFile)()
}
```

This will let webpack know that we require files at runtime. Next, we need to let webpack know how to handle the files.

In webpack.config.js:

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            /*
             * html, typescript and style rules
             */
            {
                test: /\.xlf/,
                loader: 'promise-loader?es6-promise!raw'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json/,
                loader: 'ignore-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Using the raw loader piped to the promise-loader will tell webpack to put my xlf files in a new chunk, and to load them by demand by returning a promise that will resolve to the file content when calling `require('filename')()`.

Notes:

1. You must tell promise-loader which promise library to use.
2. Because I don't tell webpack what loader to use in `require('file')` it will try to scan all files, and will complain that it cannot load .json files. That's why I had to configure a rule for json with the ignore loader.

I hope it helps.

Comment: require('filename')() always returns an error: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
I tried different paths (including relative and absolute paths), different locations -> none of them worked. Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: @RoseNettoyeur I eventually ended using this code: `System.import('./assets/locale/messages.' + locale + '.xlf')`. It works with webpack 2.0 and the path is relative to the file in which the call is found.

Comment: System.import couses an error like -> `ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Cannot find module './locale/messages.en.xlf'.
    at webpackEmptyContext`

Comment: System.import('./assets/locale/messages.' + locale + '.xlf') this returns an error: System is not defined

Answer (score 0):

With Webpack 2 I use the current configuration:

In my `webpack.config.js` I set `raw-loader` to handle `.xlf` files, this tell Webpack to load the file as pure text.

```
{
    test: /\.xlf/,
    loader: 'raw-loader'
}
```

Then in `i18n.providers.js` I defined the function as following:

```
function getTranslationsWithES6Import(locale: string) {
/**
 * System.import in Webpack is an alias of the standard dynamic import()
 * but the latter can't be used because Typescript would complain.
 * @see https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/#dynamic-import
 * @see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12364
 *
 * Also the file name must not used backticks and the file extension must be
 * within the function call otherwise Webpack won't know how to load it.
 * @see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5285#issuecomment-285059969
 */
return System.import('../assets/locale/messages.' + locale + '.xlf');
```

}